# Display ProgressRing while download image in ItemsPage

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I have an ItemsPage.
When user navigate, then application download few images.
I want to see ProgressRing on each of them.

My GridViewTemplate

```
<GridView.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          Width="150"
          Height="230">
      <Canvas>
        <ProgressRing x:Name="imageProgress"
                      Canvas.ZIndex="10"
                      Width="100"
                      Height="100"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                      Grid.Column="0" />
        <Image x:Name="FilmImage"
               Source="{Binding Image}"
               Stretch="UniformToFill"
               AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Title}" />
      </Canvas>
      <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                  Background="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlayBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"
                   Foreground="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlayForegroundThemeBrush}"
                   Style="{StaticResource TitleTextStyle}"
                   Height="60"
                   Margin="15,0,15,0" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Subtitle}"
                   Foreground="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlaySecondaryForegroundThemeBrush}"
                   Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextStyle}"
                   TextWrapping="NoWrap"
                   Margin="15,0,15,10" />
      </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
  </DataTemplate>
</GridView.ItemTemplate>
```

My .cs

```
 public sealed partial class AllCinemas : LayoutAwarePage
    {
protected async override void LoadState(Object navigationParameter, Dictionary<String, Object> pageState)
        {

            FeedAllCinemas allCinemas = new FeedAllCinemas();
            allCinemas.GetAllCinemas("", "");
            this.DefaultViewModel["Items"] = allCinemas.Cinemas;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check this awesome blog post, it is exactly what you want : [Windows 8 (or XAML generally): Loading Images with Progress/Fallback Content](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2013/03/20/windows-8-or-xaml-generally-loading-images-with-progress-fallback-content.aspx)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please check this thread, it contains a solution: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/536a3d52-0c9f-4875-8ad5-991a9eab17c8/